# Wordpress: Posts and pages content not showing but title is

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site which was working all fine but suddenly it got hacked by someone. I immediately deactivate my theme and then after sometime activate it. it got recovered but all contents of pages and posts is not showing up but title is showing. I checked databse tables. It contains all posts, also checked wp-admin. It also contains all data. Also tried by deactivating plugins and then activating it. Dont know what to do. please help me, I badly need it. Pleaseee

---

here is the link
http://islamiroohanimission.org

index page is okay. But go on any menu. it will give the message no post is found.

Comment: Without a link, it'd just be blind guessing to figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

go to your functions file and see if they messed with your DEFINE posts to remove those parts of the page.